# Django mongo db filter query is not returning any data

Tags: python, django, mongodb, document, mongo-collection

When I am trying `om = OttMessage.objects.filter()` its returning all the documents in the ott_message collections.

But when I am trying `om = OttMessage.objects.filter(prediction_status = -1)` its not returning any data.

OttMessage model.py relevant line

`prediction_status = IntField(default=-1, db_field='ps')`
For example

There are many documents in the ott_message collection having prediction_status field -1

```
  {
     "classification" : null,
     "message_from" : "XXXXXXXX",
     "id" : "5b61d4649cdae332bf9151f9",
     "is_classified" : false,
     "prediction_status" : -1,
     "post_disposition" : null,
     "message" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
     "channel" : 1,
     "message_date" : "2018-08-01T15:42:30",
     "group_name" : "Resale Gurgaon req IC",
     "req_disposition" : null,
     "manual_tagged_status" : -1
  },
  {
     "prediction_status" : -1,
     "is_classified" : false,
     "classification" : null,
     "message_from" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
     "id" : "5b61da629cdae343169150cf",
     "manual_tagged_status" : -1,
     "req_disposition" : null,
     "message" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
     "post_disposition" : null,
     "message_date" : "2018-08-01T15:50:19",
     "group_name" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
     "channel" : 1
  }
```

Can anybody tell me where its going wrong ? Thanks

Comment: Can you share (relevant) details of your `OttMessage` model?

Comment: `prediction_status = IntField(default=-1, db_field='ps')`

Comment: This is line I have newly added in OttMessage mongo colleciton

Comment: Hmm... Did you check if it is `-1`  in the `ps` key of the documents in the Mongo database?

Comment: Perhaps the migration did not run (correctly) in which case there is no `-1` for the records (well the key is missing).

Comment: I see two field in database.  `"prediction_status" : null, "ps" : 1,`

Comment: Hmmm... wel then it looks like the filter itself did its work. Did you set the value to 1.

Comment: Yes. I did set on related records by looping on 'om = OttMessage.objects.filter()' . I don't want to filter all records every time but only records which have `prediction_status = -1`